# Click по всем "show_more_matches" что есть на странице

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Код переходит на сайт, кликает во всплывающем окне на "accept. Дальше кликает по странам, тем самым открывая скрытые списки лиг и переходит по каждой лиге в новом окне. И вот дальше у меня начались проблемы так как там отображаются не все результаты матчей и в некоторых лигах надо кликнуть как раз таки на `show_more_matches`. Когда отображаются все матчи и никуда кликать не нужно или нужно кликнуть 1 раз - все работает, но когда длинная лига и надо кликать больше 1 раза то ничего не работает, даже если надо кликнуть 3 раза - код кликает 1 раз и продолжает работать дальше словно других `show_more_matches` нет. Мне же нужно чтоб он кликал на все `show_more_matches`, которые на странице.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def leagues_selection():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com")
    accept = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    for country in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block"):
        if country.is_displayed():
            country.click()
    for league in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__templateHref"):
        league_hrefs = str(league.get_attribute("href"))
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020-2021/results")
        for show_more_matches in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__more.event__more--static"):
            if show_more_matches:
                time.sleep(5)
                show_more_matches.click()
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.close()

leagues_selection()
```

Comment: Можно ссылку на длинную лигу?

Comment: @ProgerOffline, вот для примера, лига, где 1 раз нужно кликнуть (https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/superliga-2020-2021/results). А вот  лига, где нужно кликнуть 3 раза (https://www.flashscore.com/football/algeria/ligue-1-2020-2021/results)